# Google Charts - removing vAxis or row labels in Timeline chart

Tags: google-visualization

How to remove row labels in Timeline chart (they are positioned similar to vAxis in other charts)?

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for this for quite a while and finally found it burried in Google Charts documentation:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline
(look at Overlapping gridlines example).

Add this to your chart options:

```
showRowLabels: false
```